# Counter beside review button in top bar

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, reviewing

Wouldn't it be easier to have a number (maybe in brackets) beside the review button at the top to show you how many items you can currently review? At the moment you have to click the review button to see if there are any items waiting, and there might not be. While it is not a big deal, I don't see why it would hurt to add this. Any ideas?

Comment: This would add several more db pulls per page load. There is already a box for suggest edits, once you have the privilege to approve them.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this thing I made](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/11540?m=15143936#15143936) because of the same reasons. It saves a click (back to last page or clicking into review queue), and it saves a page load.

Answer (score 1):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

There was a counter added to the top bar which was there for many years, however, this has since been replaced by a simple red dot when there are many items to review:

[image: Red and grey dots in review menu]

Answer (score 0):

There is one already (actually it should be 2, one of them was removed due [reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228861/213575), but it's [being planned to be added back](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226092/lets-get-rid-of-the-10k-flag-queue#comment739620_226092), or so I hope). There is also a [feature request over MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/211509/213575) that may be interesting to you. But essentially, they are trying to bring those functions while not affecting the performance as Frank suggest.